# Sitecore and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sitecore, sitecore6

I am starting a project with Sitecore, I have looked for different possibilities. I have some experience with MVC but I don't understand why you want to combine this with Sitecore (6.4).

- What are the benefits? Are there any examples of the implementation of (the code of) this (not the configuration on: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/integrating%20an%20asp.net%20mvc%20web%20application%20in%20sitecore%20cms-usletter.pdf)?
- Or why shouldn't I use MVC with Sitecore?

So when should I use Sitecore 6.4 with MVC3 and when not? And are there any (code)examples?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully implemented my own MVP implementation using Sitecore. MVP is a bit more forgiving than MVC, and can easily be integrated into web forms based applications. I used T4 templates to generate Models directly from Sitecore templates using the built-in webservices which worked really well.

Sitecore doesn't support MVC yet (in the recommended release), and trying to make it work is probably not worth the effort. I believe they are working on a version that supports MVC properly, which may be the link you provided. However it's probably also very new and there is a lot of functionality in the old version that relies on web forms. I'd like to see it working under MVC in an official capacity for a few more iterations.

Implementing patterns such as MVC and MVP are all about separating concerns and making your presentation layer unit testable. It also encourages more elegant design.

Just reading the doc it looks like this is a guide for running Sitecore in parallel with MVC. I can't see anything about new rendering mechanisms for Sitecore, which would make templating difficult in anything other than web forms. It would however allow you to use the Sitecore API to build your own templates via MVC Views, but you would loose the inline editing functionality that you get out-of-the-box with web forms.

Answer (score 1):

Using mvp is probably the simplest way to go. I wrote a blog post about it [here.](http://sleepdeprivedcoder.blogspot.com/2011/04/model-view-presenter-mvp-and-sitecore.html)
 However, we have used MVC3 with Razor before and it worked very well. The only issue is you lose the ability to use Page edit mode as you have to do some hacking of sitecore to get it to work. I'm contemplating writing a blog post about it if people are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up.. MVC is now supported in 6.6, which will be released on November 5th 2012. We just saw a demo from John West at the Sitecore Symposium and it looks like a great framework. One of the best things about it is that you can use MVC side-by-side with Web Forms. You don't have to make an all-in bet for MVC, you can just slowly migrate or build new components in MVC, while still running Web Forms throughout your site.